# C# Form , Properties not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, boolean

I'm trying to do the popular game "**Ruzzle**" for PC See:

[image]

I am stuck on a very silly error i think but for some reason it looks like a property is not working!

I have a class called "check" that has a bool property named `Used`. If it set to true the background will change from white to orange. This is achieved with the following :

```
bool _used; 

public bool Used
{
    get { return _used; }
    set { _used = value; Invalidate(); }
}

void Check_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics area = e.Graphics;

    if (_used==false)
    {
        area.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        area.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
        ...
    }
}
```

I've assigned to `mouseClick` an event that i will define in the class `Ruzzle`.
The class `Ruzzle` handles the game wich basically is a bi-dimentional array of `Check`.

```
public event EventHandler selected;

//in the constructor I've put this
this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Check_MouseClick);
```

and finally

```
void Check_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (selected != null)
    {
        selected(this, e);
    }                

    Invalidate();
}
```

In the class `Ruzzle` I try to change the bool property of the `Check` object by doing:

```
public Ruzzle(Control father)
{ 
    myGame = new Check[4, 4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {          
            myGame[i, j] = new Check(50, father,i,j);
            myGame[i, j].Location = new Point((i * 50), (j * 50));
            father.Controls.Add(myGame[i, j]);
            myGame[i, j].selected += new EventHandler(Ruzzle_selected);
        }
    }       
}

void Ruzzle_selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int r = (sender as Check).Row;
    int c = (sender as Check).Column;
    myGame[r, c].Used = true;
}
```

The `Row` and `Column` properties are working fine becuase if I do a MessageBox.Show I get the correct values. **However when it executes the Paint method in the `Check` class the `Used` boolean won't change !**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While it may not solve your problem, remove `myGame[r, c].Invalidate();`. It's not needed, as setting `Used` already calls `Invalidate()`.

Comment: Have you debugged it to find out if the used property setter is actually being called at all?

Comment: For some reason after it executes the "myGame[r,c].Used = true" instruction it directly goes to the Paint method..so no it is not being called.Wierd. What do you think the prolem is?

Comment: How have you determined that the value is not changed?

Comment: 1)In debug i see that that the used property is still set to false.

Comment: 2)After the paint method is called it executes the instructions of the "if" conditional and not the "else" instructions .

Comment: The invalidate/paint may have been caused by something else so when you hit that breakpoint in the Check_Paint routine the setter hasn't been called yet.  You will need to be very careful while debugging your paint code.  I have seen scenarios where moving the mouse over the widget caused a repaint (which would be before your setter) before clicking on it caused another Paint.

Comment: I double checked and I'm sure that the Paint event is called when desired...I don't think that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post this as answer though this one is not going to tell what is the exact issue with your code. The code itself looks fine so you have to debug it. Let me give you some tips on how to debug this issue.

I can see two obvious possible scenarios why your `Used` property is `false`:

1. It is not being changed to `true` correctly.
2. It is reset back to `false` at some point.

So you have to check both these possibilities. First of all we should ignore all the `Check` instances except for the one which is clicked otherwise other instances might distract you while debugging. There are two easy ways to do that:

1. Instantiate only one instance. In this case you should create a 1x1 field if that is possible in your game.
2. Distinguish between distances while debugging. There is a nice feature in VS debugger called [Make object Id](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx). Basically it allows you to assign a numeric unique identifier to some object while debugging. Later you can whether specific instance is the one that you marked before by observing its Id in debugger. If you haven't used this feature before please check out the link above.

Ok, now you are debugging only instance of `Check` class. Let's start with checking whether property is set correctly. There are several points where you should check your property value, for example:

1. `Paint` handler where you have the condition.
2. Setter of `Used` property when calling the `Invalidate` method. `_used` should be definitely `true`.
3. At the end of `Ruzzle_selected` handler. `Used` property should be `true` here and you should check it. If it is `true` then we can conclude that at least it is set correctly.

Now let's check whether property `Used` is not reset back to `false`. As far as I can see in your code you should have no places where you might actually want to reset it. Which means that if you'll find such a behavior then it would probably the bug you are looking for. I assume that you do not access your `_used` field anywhere except for the `Used` property. In this case debugging this possible issue is very easy, you just have to put a breakpoint in the setter of your property and see if it is set `false`. In order to avoid breakpoint being hit when you set it to `true` you can use the [breakpoint condition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition-vstipdebug0021.aspx) feature. In your case the condition should be something like `value == false && _used == true`.

Please try debugging using these steps and let us know if it helps you. Otherwise it might be something that I have missed, in this case I'll extend the answer.